# Como obter o último dia útil do mês?

Tags: java

Há alguma biblioteca brasileira de feriados confiável que a gente consiga integrar e obter o último dia útil de algum mês?

De qualquer modo, se não houver tal biblioteca, como eu poderia obter o último dia de semana de algum mês? (Formatado em um Calendar ou um Date.)

Exemplo de código necessário

```
Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar ultimoDiaUtil = getUltimoDiaUtil(hoje);
```

Comment: Você pode obter o último dia do mês somando -1 dia à uma data que represente o primeiro dia do mês seguinte. E se quiser o último dia de semana, é só voltar os dias até encontrar uma sexta (caso o último dia já não seja). Em no máximo duas iterações você consegue o dia desejado.

Comment: Deve ser simples você manter um arquivo de configuração (um XML talvez) com os feriados nacionais e estaduais. Na interação que o @Renan mencionou, basta ignorar as datas que cairem em um feriado configurado. Fontes confiáveis de informações sobre feriados são [1](http://www.brasil.gov.br/cidadania-e-justica/2014/01/divulgada-lista-de-feriados-e-pontos-facultativos-de-2014) e [2](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feriados_no_Brasil).

Comment: @Renan sua solução é muito boa, desde que o autor não precise considerar os feriados, pq não implementa ela?

Comment: @Math porque eu sou um zero a esquerda em Java e não conheço os tipos de data e hora do framework. Se fosse .NET ou Javascript eu poderia ajudar mais. Se alguém quiser dar uma resposta completa abaixo com a minha ideia, fiquem a vontade :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Você pode obter o último dia do mês somando -1 dia à uma data que represente o primeiro dia do mês seguinte. E se quiser o último dia de semana, é só voltar os dias até encontrar uma sexta (caso o último dia já não seja). Em no máximo duas iterações você consegue o dia desejado.

Funciona desde que não considere os feriados.

Se quiser considerar os feriados, mapeie-os e adicione mais uma condição no loop verificando se a data não é um feriado, se for um feriado continue decrementando até que a condição não seja satisfeita e caia fora do `while`.

Implementando a ideia do @Renan mais a parte do código que verifica se é feriado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar ultimoDiaUtilDoMes = getUltimoDiaUtilDoMes(hoje);
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.format(ultimoDiaUtilDoMes.getTime()));
}
public static Calendar getUltimoDiaUtilDoMes(Calendar calendar) {
    //muda a data da variável para o último dia do mês
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    //enquanto for sábado, domingo ou feriado
    while(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY ||
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY || 
            ehFeriado(calendar)) {
        //decrementa a data em um dia
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);            
    }
    return calendar;
}
public static boolean ehFeriado(Calendar calendar) {
    Calendar feriado = Calendar.getInstance();
    //considerando 30 de abril como feriado
    feriado.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.APRIL, 30);
    if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == feriado.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Retorna:

> 29/04/2014

Pois no meu código disse que hoje é feriado, portanto ele mostrou a data de ontem.

Para a comparação feita no código:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == feriado.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
```

dar certo é necessário que o ano do feriado seja setado como o mesmo ano da data que vai comparar, assim:

```
feriado.set(
    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), //ano de feriado igual ao ano de calendar
    Calendar.APRIL, //constante estática da classe Calendar
    30);
```

pois o `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` retorna um inteiro que diz qual é o dia daquele ano, portanto caso seja setado 30 de abril de um ano qualquer daria diferença de um dia se comparar a data de um ano bissexto com a mesma data de um ano não bissexto.

Para considerar os feriados cuja a data varia de ano para ano deve-se descobrir a conta que é feita e implementá-la por exemplo em um método `ehFeriadoQueVaria()` e adicioná-lo no `while()`.

Edição para referência futura:

Agenda de Feriados disponibilizada pelo Google em formato [XML](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/pt-br.brazilian%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic).

Comment: `Não me lembro de nenhum feriado que vai no final do mês`  Carnaval e semana santa podem cair em final de mês. O Reveillon até onde lembro é feriado facultativo no Brasil. E do jeito que a coisa vai, o Dia das Bruxas (31 de Outubro) daqui a pouco vira feriado. Isso são os nacionais - pode ainda haver feriados estaduais ou municipais que caiam em último dia de mês. Fora isso, +1

Comment: @Renan você merece metade dos pontos que eu ganhar, rsrs.. vou editar. PS: até onde sei Reveillon não é feriado, dia 1º de janeiro que é. Realmente carnaval e feriados regionais podem ser um problema.

Comment: @Renan na verdade carnaval só é feriado no Rio e na Bahia, no restante do país é facultativo, semana santa é feriado mesmo, e varia de ano para ano, seria necessário uma bela de uma conta (se é que existe) para calculá-los. Feriados regionais geralmente não mudam de data, então não seria nenhum problema.

Comment: Carnaval e semana santa são baseados na lua. Parecem aleatórios, mas é uma conta conhecida. Posso confirmar que o Carnaval é feriado em todos os estados do Nordeste ao menos, até onde sei. Originalmente era um feriado católico e era um dos poucos que a Ditadura não conseguiu remover do calendário oficial em eras passadas, para se ter uma ideia da importância dele...

Comment: @Renan Posso dizer que carnaval não é feriado em SP, pois já trabalhei no carnaval e não ganhei nada mais por isso, rs..

Comment: Muito interessante pessoal. Realmente a ideia dessa iteração tornou o cálculo bem rápido mesmo. E a ideia de colocar em um XML é uma boa também. Acho que não compensa ficar tentanto fazer cálculos para encontrar... acho que é melhor para cada ano adicionar um arquivo com as informações mesmo...

Comment: Pessoal, aproveitando as interessantes idéias desse post, encontrei uma agenda que eu diria ser confiável, com os feriados do Brasil (nacionais apenas) já em XML. A agenda disponibilizada pelo [Google](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/pt-br.brazilian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic). Se fosse necessário adicionar feriados regionais, bastaria baixar o arquivo, importar em uma agenda personalizada e depois exportar novamente. Faltaria agora os métodos para ler o XML e retirar as informações...

Answer (score -2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    //alterar para o mes de abril
    c.set(Calendar.MONDAY, Calendar.APRIL);
    //pega o ultimo dia do mes de abril
    int ultimoDia =c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: e pra pegar o último dia útil?

Answer (score -2):

Para não seguires códigos muito grandes e complexos, te sugiro, este código feito por mim, e te sugiros que sigas os tutorias no próprio site da Oracle!

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class testee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("primeiro dia do mês: " + principioDoMes(LocalDate.now()));
        System.out.println("ultimo dia do mês: " + fimDoMes(LocalDate.now()));
    }

    private static LocalDate principioDoMes(LocalDate l) {

        String local = l.toString();
        int ano = Integer.parseInt(local.split("-")[0]);
        int mes = Integer.parseInt(local.split("-")[1]);

        return LocalDate.of(ano, mes, 1);
    }

    private static LocalDate fimDoMes(LocalDate l) {
        return principioDoMes(l.plusMonths(1)).minusDays(1);
    }
}
```